# Code examples in Doxygen

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

In my comments in doxygen I am using example code. But comments are getting very long with 20 lines of php-code in them. Is there a way to have the examples in a different file?

How would I do this?

I tried @example but the result was, that the class was not longer listed in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered creating a "samples" directory (or something similar) to house all of your examples then use \link to tie it together?

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlink

Comment: Sounds sensible. But how to specify the path? I have put my example in the same directory and added the link. But the link that I get does not link to the file, but to the same doc file that the link is in. I supplied the file name as parameter to @link though.